# How to make UIWebView go to requested URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, theos

I am building a browser app and I have a UIWebView and a textField I need to know what code I would put in my button to make the URL put in the textField display in the UIWebView

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];   // x is width,y is hght


NSString *urlAddress =     @"http://www.livewiretech.co.nf/Web_app/Home.html";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

I have a textfield

```
    // Create Text Field
    UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc]       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 200, 40)];
    [myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [myTextField setText:@"http://Www.url.com"];
    [[self view] addSubview:myTextField];
    [myTextField release];
```

This is my button

```
    -(void) goButton {
    //code here
    }
```

Comment: don't release the myTextField object and also it should be a property so that myTextField.text can be accessed in goButton.

Comment: So what would that look like?

Comment: I have shown you that in below example. Can you share your code?

Comment: All my coding is above i tried what you put below is just gives a lot of errors i think your giving me stuff that would be done in Xcode which i do not have

Comment: In my RootViewController.h i have declared a UIButton *goButton;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a UITextField and a Go button next to it at the top. Let user input URL in textField and on press of Go button pass the url to UIWebView loadRequest method.

You need to adjust the UI accordingly to have UITextField at the top and below that UIWebView

Updated Answer

Initialise your UIWebView as a property in .h file.

In your .h file create following properties

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *urlText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

In your .m file

```
-(void)viewDidLaod {
    self.urlText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 11, 229, 25)];
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40, 300, 500)];    
    UIButton *goButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    goButton.frame = CGRectMake(235, 11, 25, 25);
    [goButton setTitle:@"GO" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [goButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubView:self.urlText];
    [self.view addSubView:goButton];
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
 }



-(void)goButton:(id)sender {
 NSString *urlAddress = self.urlText.text;
 NSURL *url = [NSURL    URLWithString:urlAddress];   
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
 [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: Im getting errors will this work considering i dnt have xcode

Comment: Undeclared identifier textfield

Comment: You need to create a UITextField property also. If you are creating textfield using xib then you need to connect the property with the textfield in xib

Comment: Then create a UITextField like you create the UIWebView, set the frame accordingly... and use that UITextField property in go button method

Comment: This really looks likes its on the right track but now im getting a bunch of errors when i run "make package install" its saying object not declared in RootViewController

Comment: Not how are doing it.. Do you have Xcode where you can try this out.. Also spell of viewDidLaod is incorrect. It Should be viewDidLoad.

Comment: I redid my question hopefully that will be a lot easier to answer